# nodejs: How to store multiple events of same name for unit test

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mocha.js

For unit testing (with mocha) I would like to setup some sort of asynchronous queue for events.

Until now I have setup a once() Promise to wait for events:

```
import EventEmitter from 'events'
import { once } from 'events'
import { strict as assert } from 'assert'

describe('tests', function () {
    const emitter = new EventEmitter()

    it('testcase-1', async function () {
        const ecmConfigurationPromise1 = once(emitter, 'event')
        setTimeout(() => {
            emitter.emit('event', { a: 1 })
        })
        assert.equal((await ecmConfigurationPromise1)[0].a, 1)
    })
})
```

(`setTimeout(...)` represent triggering my application)

However now I need to be able to capture multiple events with the same name, and would like to follow the same pattern of awaiting for them. My idea was to store the events on some async queue (XXX below), but I cannot find any such thing.

```
import EventEmitter from 'events'
import { strict as assert } from 'assert'

describe('tests', function () {
    const emitter = new EventEmitter()

    it('testcase-2', async function () {
        emitter.on('event', (msg) => XXX.push(msg))
        setTimeout(() => {
            emitter.emit('event', { a: 1 })
            emitter.emit('event', { a: 2 })
        })
        assert.equal((await XXX)[0].a, 1)
        assert.equal((await XXX)[0].a, 2)
        // nice to have:
        assert.equal(XXX.length(), 0)
    })
})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems no-one has a solution off the shelf, so I will share my own solution.

The resulting test case is reasonably simple:

```
it('testcase-2', async function () {
    const eventPromise = waitForMultipleEvents('event', 3, (result, msg) => {
        result.value += msg.a
    })

    setTimeout(() => {  // simulate application under test
        emitter.emit('event', { a: 1 })
        emitter.emit('event', { a: 2 })
    })

    await eventPromise
})
```

The work is done in

```
const eventPromise = waitForMultipleEvents('event', 3, (result, msg) => {
    result.value += msg.a
})
```

The arrow function is called for each event and does some test specific analysis, and stores the result in result.value. When result.value equals the supplied parameter `3`, the promise will fullfil, and in case of timeout it will reject.

The following boiler plate makes it happen (type script)

```
function sleep(ms: number) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms)
    })
}

/**
 * Helper function to wait for multiple occurences of same event. Needed
 * because once() can only be used to catch a single shot of the same event.
 *
 * @param event bus event
 * @param expect expected end value for result.value
 * @param eventHandler function must be provided to analyze the received
 * events. It should store its state in result.value
 *
 * @returns promise will resolve when result.value equals `expect` or reject
 * on timeout.
 */
async function waitForMultipleEvents(
    event: string,
    expect: number,
    eventHandler: (result: { value: number }, message: any) => void
): Promise<void> {
    const result = { value: 0 }
    emitter.on(event, (msg) => eventHandler(result, msg))

    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if (result.value == expect) {
            break
        }
        await sleep(20)
    }

    await sleep(20) // Wait for additinal
    emitter.removeAllListeners(event)
    assert.equal(result.value, expect, `Too few/many ${event} received`)
}
```